# Change prefix namespaces to default namespace in python using lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces

What would be the most pythonic way how to change prefix namespaces (namespaces defined and used by prefix) to default namespace using lxml in python3?

Example of input xml:

```
<ns0:a xmlns:ns0="some_custom_ns">
  <ns0:b>
    <ns0:c>abcabc</ns0:c>
  </ns0:b>
  <ns0:b>
    <ns0:c>defdef</ns0:c>
  </ns0:b>
</ns0:a>
```

Example of output xml:

```
<a xmlns="some_custom_ns">
  <b>
    <c>abcabc</c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>defdef</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

Comment: It is a task for XSLT.

Comment: I cannot think of an elegant, "pythonic" way to do this using the lxml API. I would do it the "ugly" way by treating the XML as plain text and doing search/replace.